# how to get queryset from django orm create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i want to get queryset as a return value when i use the create in django orm

```
newUserTitle = User_Title.objects.none()    
newUserTitle = newUserQuestTitle | newUserReviewTitle
newUserTitle = newUserQuestTitle | newUserReviewTitle | newUserlevelTitle
```

i want add three objects(newUserQuestTitle, newUserReviewTitle, newUserlevelTitle) as queryset

Comment: This is extremely unclear.  What are newUserReviewTitle and newUserlevelTitle? Why is newUserTitle a `none` queryset? What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Can you be more specific and clear what do you want?

Comment: newUserQuestTitle, newUserReviewTitle, newUserlevelTitle are object from database. i want to sum this three object to one and to make queryset

Comment: Sorry about my unclear question. In my view three different objects are created(three kind of title) and i want to send this objects as json data using serializer at one time. So i want to make three object to one query set

Answer (score 0):

```
newUserTitle = User_Title.objects.none()
newUserTitle = newUserTitle.union(newUserQuestTitle)
newUserTitle = newUserTitle.union(newUserReviewTitle)
newUserTitle = newUserTitle.union(newUserlevelTitle)
```

if newUserQuestTitle, newUserReviewTitle and newUserlevelTitle also the query set then this will work.

I did not understand your question completely but This might help you.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i got error like following code                       "object has no attribute '_combinator_query'"

Comment: i am making Title objects like " newUserReviewTitle = User_Title.objects.create(user_num_id=user_id, title_num_id=10)" from this code object.create return object. do you know how to get this as query set ?

Comment: try with query set I am not sure why this error coming, ok still with query set.

Comment: `newUserTitle = newUserTitle._combinator_query('union', newUserQuestTitle)`
`newUserTitle = newUserTitle._combinator_query('union', newUserReviewTitle)`
`newUserTitle = newUserTitle._combinator_query('union', newUserlevelTitle)`
please try this as well

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you are asking, or why you want to do this - if you have three elements from the database already, I don't see why you need a queryset. But the way to do it would be to get the PKs of those items and query them:

```
pks = [newUserQuestTitle.pk, newUserReviewTitle.pk, newUserlevelTitle.pk]
newUserTitle = User_Title.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
```

(Separately, please use proper Python style; User_Title should be UserTitle, and the other objects should be lower_case_with_underscore: `new_user_title`, `new_user_review_title` etc.)

Comment: Sorry about my unclear question. In my view three different objects are created(three kind of title) and i want to send this objects as json data using serializer at one time. So i want to make three object to one query set

Comment: i did not know python style that you are saying. I will change it thank you

Comment: three elements is not in the database. three elements is created as object in view. my questions is wrong sorry

Comment: Then your requirement is impossible. A queryset is a collection of elements that represent a query in the database.

Comment: i resolve my problem from your advice(pks = [newUserQuestTitle.pk, newUserReviewTitle.pk, newUserlevelTitle.pk]
newUserTitle = User_Title.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)). thank you