# Error 'Product' object has no attribute '_combinator_query'

Tags: python, django

I am creating an e-commerce website in django where the homepage can be changed dynamically by changing the instances of `FeaturedProduct` objects. These objects have two `ForeignKeys`. First is to the `Product` class and the other is to `FeaturedCategory` class(this is for the type of deal, eg: daily deals, new arrivals, etc). So, I'm trying to get the `Product` instances in a queryset instead of the `FeaturedProduct` queryset. When I union two querysets, I get an error that `'Product' object has no attribute '_combinator_query'`. The codes have been shown below.

My models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='1')
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='2')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desc = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    avg_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    avg_rating_float = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    number_of_ratings = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", default="")
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", default="")
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, help_text=('Leave this parameter empty, it will get generated automatically.'))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.product_name)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

class FeaturedCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Featured Categories"

class FeaturedProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured_category = models.ForeignKey(FeaturedCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_name
```

My views.py

```
def index(request):
    prod = Product.objects.none()
    feat = FeaturedProduct.objects.all()
    for pro in feat:
        ob = Product.objects.get(product_name=pro.product)
        print(ob.product_name)
        print(ob.category)
        print(ob.sub_category)
        print(ob.price)
        prod.union(ob) # Error found here
    
    # Working part
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

The last three lines are working fine, but not the other part of the index function.
Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Hi Adarsh , one question before I post what may be a probable answer, the area where you have `print(ob.product_name)` and the other items, do they actually give any output 
 or just print None ?

Comment: @PaulWekesa Yes. the product name, category and other details are printed. It does not show None.

Comment: Sorry I took sometime but I am back, still not posting an answer still I don't have one but a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58134815/11549977, try out the last comment.

Comment: Otherwise if that does not work, please add the output for print(dir(prod)) so that we can see what are the specific function names and variables of your objects. 

I have replicated your code but literally getting no error at my end. Works just fine.

Comment: @PaulWekesa I read that comment, but I changed the view in a different way. Now I pass `feat` in the products dictionary. Also, I have removed the for loop, `prod` and `products`. In my template I have to access the object attributes by `product.product.product_name`. Now it is working fine. Thank you, Paul for your time and effort. I really appreciate it 